# Difference between autoconf and autoreconf

Tags: autotools, autoconf, autoreconf

I'm trying to learn how to use autotools and I can't seem to find a good beginner-friendly answer to this question. What's the difference between `autoconf` and `autoreconf`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`autoconf` generates the `configure` script from various input files, some of which are created using other tools like `aclocal`, `automake`, etc.

`autoreconf` is a helper that knows how to call all these tools in the right order

You'll usually just call `autoreconf` yourself and let it deal with all the lower level tools ....

Comment: And `autoconf` is a low-level tool used by `autoreconf`?

Comment: Maybe bad wording on my side, autoconf, automake, libtool etc are the actual work horses. 

autoreconf is more like a wrapper that knows what the right order to call all the others in is.

It is more like an orchestrator, similar to make, but with a fixed set of rules.

Comment: You're probably right. It's just that the naming seems weird. It seems to suggest that to generate (the first time) `configure` you run `autoconf`, but for regeneration you need `autoreconf`.

Comment: "autoreconf runs autoconf, autoheader, aclocal, automake, libtoolize, and autopoint (when appropriate) repeatedly to update the GNU Build System in the specified directories and their subdirectories"
https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.68/html_node/autoreconf-Invocation.html
It is that simple.